# can`t get response with add_action wpcf7_mail_sent

Tags: php, wordpress

I've create a function in WordPress to send various emails after *wpcf7_mail_sent* hook is catched. The email is sends ok, but in the front end the user doesn't recive any response after submit form (the form stay loading permanently and don't give any success message or similar).

In functions.php i have this:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'contact_form_autoresponse' );

function contact_form_autoresponse( $contact_form ) {
    include('cf7_response.php');
}
```

And cf7_response.php file have this:

```
if( $contact_form->id == xxxx // the id form ) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $mail = $posted_data['email'];
    $subject = 'My subject';
    $msg = 'My message';
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'From: xxxxx@xxxx' // my email
    mail( $mail, $subject, $msg, $header );
}
```

How i say, the mail is send Ok, but the form just show loading permanently and doesn't give the success message, like it's waiting for some response from the function.

Answer (score 0):

If your `cf7_response.php` is exactly what you've pasted in your question there's a syntax error in it, and I believe that the AJAX request made on the front of your site will throw a 500 response sometime *after* the request is processed. This would explain the initial email sending okay but the form hanging.

Try this, instead:

```
if( $contact_form->id == xxxx // the id form ) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $mail = $posted_data['email'];
    $subject = 'My subject';
    $msg = 'My message';
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'From: any@valid.email'; // <-- fixed unclosed quote on this line
    mail( $mail, $subject, $msg, $header );
}
```

(If this proves to have been the problem, have a look into a [php linter](https://github.com/search?q=php%20linter) to help you catch these types of problems before you even leave your editor to test the code!)

Additionally - it's possible that the error is caused by the `include` if `cfs7_response.php` isn't included cleanly. Try this alteration, too!

`require get_template_directory() . '/cf7_response.php';`

Comment: Thanks Cameron, i fix the code (that was while i was writing this post) but the problem persists. I think maybe cf7 is waiting to receive some  return to continue with the script after the hook/function...

Comment: No problem @JorgedelCampoAndrade – usually 'actions', rather than filters don't require a return value, but it doesn't hurt to give a return value, for testing's sake. Btw, I've updated my answer with another theory. :)